# Swiper does not show up on ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

Swiper (or just the ng-template part) does not show up on ionic angular

The recommendation from Ionic Framework is to use SwiperJs (https://swiperjs.com/) instead of Ion Slider ( which will be deprecated on next Ionic Version 7 )

Lib Versions

```
"@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
"@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
"swiper": "^8.0.7",
```

The "SwiperModule" module is properly put in the imports in the app.module.ts

There are no errors in the console. See Picture

Component Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import Swiper core and required modules;
import SwiperCore from 'swiper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper-carousel',
  // templateUrl: './swiper-carousel.component.html',
  template: 
  `
    <swiper
      [slidesPerView]="3"
      [spaceBetween]="50"
      (swiper)="onSwiper($event)"
      (slideChange)="onSlideChange()"
    >
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
      <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
    </swiper>
  `
,
  styleUrls: ['./swiper-carousel.component.scss'],
})
export class SwiperCarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  onSwiper([swiper]) {
    console.log(swiper);
  }
  onSlideChange() {
    console.log('slide change');
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "swiper-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "3.4.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.4.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "swiper": "^8.0.7",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.2.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.4.3",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need Swiper in just one component/Page then you should import and declare it in that module only. Declaration in app.module.ts won't work.

Example:
home.page.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  // templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  template:`
  <ion-content>
  <swiper
    [slidesPerView]="3"
    [spaceBetween]="50"
    (swiper)="onSwiper($event)"
    (slideChange)="onSlideChange()"
  >
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
  </swiper>
  <app-trial-component></app-trial-component>
  </ion-content>
`,
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  public customDropdownOptions = {
    size: 'auto',
    reference: 'trigger',
    side: 'bottom',
    alignment: 'end',
  };
  text = 'normal text';
  constructor() {}
  changeColor() {
    this.text = 'changed';
  }
  onSwiper([swiper]) {
    console.log(swiper);
  }
  onSlideChange() {
    console.log('slide change');
  }

}
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';
import {TrialComponentComponent} from '../trial-component/trial-component.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule,
    SwiperModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage,TrialComponentComponent]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

When facing an issue where Swiper does not show up in an Ionic Angular application, there are several steps you can take to diagnose and solve the problem. Here are some solutions tailored to common issues based on the contexts provided:

Ensure Correct Installation and Import: Make sure you have correctly installed Swiper and imported it into your Angular module. As Swiper has become the default slider for Ionic from version 6 onwards, you need to ensure that it's properly set up in your project. For Angular projects, also verify that Swiper's Angular module is imported in the specific module where you intend to use it, rather than in the app-wide module 3 .

Check for Updates: If you recently updated your Ionic version to, for instance, 5.7.0 or above, and are trying to replace ion-slides with Swiper, ensure that Swiper is fully compatible with the version of Ionic and Angular you're using. Compatibility issues may arise, especially if you've migrated from older versions where ion-slides was prevalent 2 .

Initialize Swiper Correctly: If you're using Swiper with Ionic and Angular, ensure that you've followed the correct initialization procedures. With the removal of ion-slides in Ionic 7, Swiper must be correctly initialized in your component or page to work as expected. This might involve configuring Swiper options directly in your template or component class 11 .

Autoplay Issues: If the autoplay feature of Swiper isn't working, this might not be directly related to Swiper not showing up but could indicate a misconfiguration. Ensure that the autoplay module is correctly imported and configured in your Angular component. Specific configurations might be necessary to make autoplay work as expected 8 .

Confirm Swiper's Visibility: On a more basic level, ensure that the Swiper component is correctly included in your HTML template and that there are no CSS styles that inadvertently hide the Swiper container or its slides. Mistakes in styling or template syntax might lead to the Swiper not being visible 1 .

Address Potential Bugs: If you're encountering errors such as TypeError: mod is not a ... when using Ionic Swiper with certain versions of Angular or Swiper.js, this could indicate a version compatibility issue or a bug. In cases where Swiper throws exceptions or doesn’t behave as expected, checking for known issues on platforms like GitHub or seeking updates that address these bugs could solve the problem 5 .

Consult Documentation and Community: Finally, leverage the wealth of knowledge available in the Ionic Framework documentation, forums, and communities. With ion-slides removed in favor of Swiper, the official Ionic Academy, forums, and other community channels can offer updated guides, troubleshooting tips, and advice for common problems 4 7 .

By following these steps and adjusting your approach based on the specific issue you’re encountering, you should be able to resolve the problem of Swiper not displaying in your Ionic Angular application.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)? A warning should have appeared in the answer box where you typed (well, pasted) this answer.